# Check for the loading of an API

Tags: javascript, api, event-listener

I have a script to execute for elements of an API (named ButterCMS), and I have to wait for the loading of the API to execute this code. If not, the elements of the API are not yet created and the script return an error.

The problem is that is can’t find how to do that. I have already tried `MutationObserver`, checking for a HTTP request etc. Maybe I am doing it wrong.

I didn't found "I've finished loading" event in the docs of the API and I also searched for a event listener but without success.

Here is the code for load the API :

```js
const Butter = require('buttercms') 
export const butter = Butter('your-api-token')
```

Comment: You can keep a `loading` variable and put your api call in an async await call. So when the api call is initiated set `loading=true` and based on that show a spinner or something. await the response and the set the loading to false.

Comment: Assuming the API, or it's SDK, don't expose any public events for you to hook to, then a MutationObserver is your only workable solution - assuming that the DOM gets updated with new content when the request completed. Can you please edit your question to show what you tried.

Comment: @buzz that assumes the calls made to `Butter()` return promises.

Comment: @buzz can you show me how to do that? I didn't find.

Comment: Where are you trying to implement this code? do you use a FE library for your project or you have a plain HTML,JS project?  https://buttercms.com/docs/api-client/react/ this link shows some example, so it is likely that there is an example for your needs

Comment: I am using Nuxt.js

Comment: share what you have done...I cannot understand by seeing only two lines

Comment: Thank you @DenizKaradağ ! I think I found. I post my code as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this code the page where I want to execute my script and it work :

```js
butter.page.retrieve("*", "simple-page").then(() => {
  const createScript = document.createElement("script");
  createScript.src = "../script/post-informations.js";
  document.head.appendChild(createScript);
});
```

Thank you for your help!